# FizzBuzz Lambda Only Returning Last Integer

Tags: scheme, racket, fizzbuzz

I'm new to Scheme and trying to write a sample FizzBuzz function. Here are the rules:

- If a number is divisible by 3 and by 5, instead say "fizzbuzz"
- Else if a number is divisible by 3, instead say "fizz"
- Else if a number is divisible by 5, instead say "buzz"
- Otherwise say the number.

Here is my code:

```
(define (fizzbuzz n)
  (print (fizzbuzz1 1 n)))

;; Helper function for fizzbuzz
(define (fizzbuzz1 i n)
  (cond [(and (= 0 (modulo i 3)) (= 0 (modulo i 5)))
         " fizzbuzz "]
        [(= 0 (modulo i 3))
         " fizz "]
        [(= 0 (modulo i 5))
         " buzz "]
        (i))

  (cond [(< i n) (fizzbuzz1 (+ 1 i) n)]))

(fizzbuzz 21)
```

But all that it is displaying is "21" (from the test case). Could someone please help me out?

EDIT: Fixed my code up a bit and updated it, but now I'm getting `#<void>` printed out instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function actually calculates the correct result for all the numbers from 1 to 21, simply you do not do anything to display them in the output, or collect them is some way, so that they are “lost” after being calculated inside `fizzbuzz1` (the initial `print` only print the result of `fizzbuzz1`, which is `#<void>`). If you want to display them (by using `display` instead of `print`, for a more aesthetic result), you could put a `display` in each branch of the `cond`, for instance like this (and note that if you want to learn these kind of languages you should definitely start to indent your functions in a clean way!):

```
(define (fizzbuzz n)
  (fizzbuzz1 1 n))

(define (fizzbuzz1 i n)
  (cond [(and (= 0 (modulo i 3) ) (= 0 (modulo i 5) ))
         (display " fizzbuzz ")]
        [(= 0 (modulo i 3))
         (display " fizz ")]
        [(= 0 (modulo i 5))
         (display " buzz ")]
        [else (display i) (display " ")]
        )
  (cond [(< i n) (fizzbuzz1 (+ 1 i) n)])
  )
```

Note the  also that the final `#void` is due to the value of the print function inside the initial definition of `fizzbuzz`, and if you remove it this will disappear.

Another<del>, more elegant,</del> possibility is to collect all the strings while they are calculated, for instance by using `string-append`, like in this function:

```
(define (fizzbuzz n)
   (fizzbuzz1 1 n))

(define (fizzbuzz1 i n)
  (if (> i n)
      ""
      (string-append
       (cond [(and (= 0 (modulo i 3) ) (= 0 (modulo i 5) ))
              " fizzbuzz "]
             [(= 0 (modulo i 3))
              " fizz "]
             [(= 0 (modulo i 5))
              " buzz "]
             [else (~a " " i " ")]
             )
       (fizzbuzz1 (+ 1 i) n))))
```

Note that also in this case is not necessary to “print” the result if your program is used inside an interactive environment (like DrRacket).

**Edit**

This solution is less efficient that the first one, but should gives you an idea of what kind of structure the program should have if you need to collect all the results in some structure to use them for some other task. As another example, you could collect them by using `cons`, for instance, to produce a list of strings instead of a single string (simply substitute `'()` for `""` and `cons` for `string-append`).

Comment: You say the `string-append` approch is more elegant, but I cringe when I see it. It's like seeing string `+=` in a loop (versus using a `StringBuilder`), which is a Schlemiel the Painter problem.

Comment: I edited the answer, but I think that one that is learning recursion should first learn how to program, and then how to program efficiently. Of course your experience could be different from mine.

Comment: You can do recursion using `cons`. Doing recursion with `append` (or anything related to it) is just asking for Schlemiel the Painter. :-) You can, for example, cons up a list of strings, then do one single `string-append` with the results (using `apply`).

Comment: This answer has most of the basics right, but I find the indentation advice to be bad (in general, a line should never have a sole parenthesis on it! See the [canonical Scheme style guide](http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt)). Furthermore, building up a string like that is not a good fit for the kind of task at hand; you should indeed just display it in the `cond`.

Comment: I am writing this program inside DrRacket. The thing that I don't understand is WHEN do I need to put a print statement and when do I not. Because I wrote a different function a couple of days ago that returned the max number in a list. And in that case, I didn't need to tell it to display to console, it just did on it's own.

Comment: Inside an interactive environment, like DrRacket, any expression is evaluated and its result (the value of the expression) is always printed. For instance, if you call a function that returns a list, the list is printed automatically. You *must* call `print` or `display` a certain value when your function returns something different from it, or if the function calculate “incrementally” something and you want to see or display those partial results. For instance, you can use `print` to “debug” the code by looking at what happen in certain points, even if DrRackets has very good tools for this.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, if you are using racket (since you used the racket tag), you might find racket's [`for`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%29%29) construct useful here.

Using `for` (and using `display` as Renzo said) you can write fizzbuzz like this:

```
#lang racket

(define (fizzbuzz n)
  (for ([i (in-range n)])
    (cond [(and (= 0 (modulo i 3)) (= 0 (modulo i 5)))
           (displayln "fizzbuzz")]
          [(= 0 (modulo i 3))
           (displayln "fizz")]
          [(= 0 (modulo i 5))
           (displayln "buzz")]
          [else (displayln i)])))

(fizzbuzz 21)
```

Another option is to use [`for/list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for%2Flist#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29), which is like `for`, but accumulates the result into a list:

```
#lang racket

(define (fizzbuzz n)
  (for/list ([i (in-range n)])
    (cond [(and (= 0 (modulo i 3)) (= 0 (modulo i 5)))
           "fizzbuzz"]
          [(= 0 (modulo i 3))
           "fizz"]
          [(= 0 (modulo i 5))
           "buzz"]
          [else i])))

(fizzbuzz 21)
(apply string-append (fizzbuzz 21))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into the for loop for Racket. We haven't covered it in class yet, so I'm not sure if I would be allowed to use it on this assignment.